# ManagementClass getting HRESULT: 0x80010002 error

Tags: c#, .net

My app is getting this error on Windows 7.
Does the " Windows Management Instrumentation"  service need to be is started on the computer for this class? 
Any ideas?

BTW, this code runs fine on my computer --  So the code does work. A remote user is getting this error.

> Void Initialize()... Call was canceled by the message filter.
>   (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80010002 (RPC_E_CALL_CANCELED)) ... ...
>   at System.Management.ManagementScope.Initialize()   at
>   System.Management.ManagementObject.Initialize(Boolean getObject)   at
>   System.Management.ManagementClass.GetInstances(EnumerationOptions
>   options)

The offending C# code is this

```
ManagementClass mc = new ManagementClass(
            "Win32_LogicalDisk");
        ManagementObjectCollection moc = mc.GetInstances();
```

Comment: IS WMI service running on the computer?

Comment: @danish, Not sure if the WMI service is running on user's the computer. But the code runs fine on my computer whether the WMI service is started or stopped. Will ask the user tomorrow.

Comment: After more reading, I wonder if this error can be caused by Possible WMI Repository corruption?